# Creating an expression to add and subtract the value of two independent lookup expressions

Tags: reporting-services

I would like to create the field 'Difference' and have it use a value from an expressions cases on hand, subtract the value cases ordered, and add the value cases staged.  So ideally Difference = CASES ON HAND - CASES ORDERED + CASES ALLOCATED.  I have a matrix table that I am using and I just want to have the difference column grab the value from cases on hand subtract cases ordered, and add cases allocated.

I have tried referencing the look up expressions and using the appropriate arithmetic functions, however the intellisense sees an error.

'CASES ON HAND' Expression =

```
=Lookup(Fields!FRGNAME.Value,
Fields!FrgnName.Value, 
Fields!Cases_on_hand.Value,"DataSet2")
```

'CASES ORDERED' Expression =

```
=Sum(Fields!CASES.Value)
```

'Cases allocated' Expression =

```
=Lookup(Fields!FRGNAME.Value,
Fields!SHORT_NAME.Value,
Fields!Cases_Allocated.Value, "DataSet3")
```

The intellisense highlights the whole second expression, so I am unable to execute the report as I am sure the value will not pull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each expression is being used in another textbox, you should be able to refer to the value of each textbox in your difference textbox.

```
= ReportItems!CasesOnHandTextbox.Value 
  - ReportItems!CasesOrderedTextbox.Value 
  + ReportItems!CasesAllocatedTextbox.Value
```

Comment: Thank you Very much Steve-o169! You win the internet today! for your prize please accept my humble gratitude sir.  I hope you have an excellent weekend.  For other users trying to do this in the future, you can find your textbox numbers by right clicking on the fields properties and finding the corresponding number.  I couldn't reference the fields by name, I had to use the text box number.